# "Update a Trigger" after an alter table command MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, alter, ddl-trigger

I would like to know if it's possible in MYSQL to "update a trigger" (drop and recreate),  after an alter table command?
If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not automatically. You'll just have to do it manually. Unfortunately, the information_schema.TRIGGERS table also doesn't have any creation/alteration datetime, so you can't even write a SQL script that identifies which triggers you might need to recreate.